# In Linux I want to add count files and echo the count to a log

Tags: linux, sh

I have the script below where I do a find and then remove the files found and I want to add a count of how many files I will be removing to this command is there a way to do that? Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
find /home/dir/test/*.log -mtime +10 ! -name 'HTTPListener.log' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: `find [...] -print | wc -l > logfile` should work as long as none of the files have linebreaks in their names.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'll give it a try.  I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/dir/test/*.log -mtime +10 ! -name 'HTTPListener.log' -exec rm {} \; -print | wc -l
```

Add `-print` to ensure that the selected filenames are echoed. `wc -l` counts lines, and since each file that was deleted was echoed on a separate line, it will give you the count of the deleted items.

(Provided the file names don't contain a newline, of course, but that's pretty rare).

Comment: Thanks as well.  Your time and help are appreciated.